# What are the limits for the number of physical parameters stored in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

May I ask how many physical parameters Apache IoTDB can store in one time series at most? We may have more than 2,000 physical parameters under one device, so I want to know are there any limits for the parameter settings in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the number of physical parameter settings in the time series of Apache IoTDB, therefore there's no problem storing thousands of physical parameters you need.